# Closing a graphics window whenever the user wants it to

Tags: python, python-3.x, graphics

I have this program that makes dots move from the top to the bottom:

```
import graphics
import random

window = graphics.GraphWin("Snow!", 400, 400)

window.setBackground("skyblue")

flakes = []
for i in range(500):#generates snow
   x = random.randint(0, 400)
   y = random.randint(0, 400)
   p = graphics.Point(x, y)
   p.setFill("white")
   p.draw(window)
   flakes.append(p)

while True:#moves the 'snow'
    for f in flakes:
    f.move(0, 2)
if f.getY( ) > 399:
  f.move(0, -400)
```

i want it to be closed any way or, using the:

```
getMouse()
```

statement while the 'snow is still falling'. If i prompt the user something it will just stop (freeze).

Comment: What are you promoting the user with? can you show us that code?

Comment: if i prompt the user to click the mouse

Comment: Can you edit the question to add in the code for the prompt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep updating the screen while every tick get the mouse and see if it has clicked inside the graphics window.

See [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30136270/checking-if-clicks-are-within-a-graphic-object-python-graphics-module) for an example.