# I have a polygon , and I know all of 4 points. How do I determine if a given point is inside the polygon with OpenLayers?

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I referred this post
[How to determine if a point is inside a 2D convex polygon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8721406/how-to-determine-if-a-point-is-inside-a-2d-convex-polygon)

But I want to do the same in OSM with Open Layers.Please help me.

```
[Link](http://jsfiddle.net/Sanju5390/3tpLs6w3/)
```

Comment: Actually OpenLayers 3 contains the algorithm to check if a point is inside a polygon ([ol.geom.Geometry.containsCoordinate](https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/blob/3595c2c/src/ol/geom/geometry.js#L132-L138)), but the method is not exported in the API. If you think it should be exported, feel free to open an issue: https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with [turf.js](http://turfjs.org) using [turf.inside](http://turfjs.org/static/docs/module-turf_inside.html):

```
var polygon = new ol.Feature(new ol.geom.Polygon([[[-5e6, -1e6], [-4e6, 1e6],
            [-3e6, -1e6], [-5e6, -1e6]]]));
var point = new ol.Feature(new ol.geom.Point([-4e6, 0e6]));

var format = new ol.format.GeoJSON();
var isInside = turf.inside(
    format.writeFeatureObject(point),
    format.writeFeatureObject(polygon));
console.log(isInside);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/d6o81vc7/22/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I found this was useful for me. http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.12/examples/intersects.html

Comment: Note that the example you've posted is for OL 2 and not OL 3.