# How do I determine which triangle did the user touch in this rectangle?

Tags: android, algorithm, math

I made an Android custom view that looks like a D-Pad (image below). Given the touched coordinate (x,y), rectangle width (w), and rectangle height (h), ignoring the white diagonal and rounded corners, could somebody help me how do I determine which triangle that the user touch?

Additional info: (0,0) is upper left corner

[image: D-Pad Image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8721406/how-to-determine-if-a-point-is-inside-a-2d-convex-polygon

Comment: That will work, but it's swatting flies with an F16. Waaay too complicated and slow for this trivial example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shift the origin to the center: subtract `w/2` from `x` and `h/2` from `y`. If it's not a square (say `w` is greater than `h`) then normalize the larger dimension: `x *= h; x /= w;` Then, the four sections can be determined as follows:

```
x < 0, |y| < |x| = left
x > 0, |y| < |x| = right
y < 0, |x| < |y| = up
y > 0, |x| < |y| = down
```

(Any other condition, such as x=y=0, or |x|=|y|, means you're on the diagonals).

Comment: What if the rectangle is not a square?